# How can I customize vue2-editor style?

Tags: vuejs2

First of all, I wrapped VueEditor component.

`WYSIWYG.vue`

```html
<template>
  <VueEditor
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor'

export default {
  components: {
    VueEditor
  }
}
</script>
```

Right now everything works fine. According to the [documentation](https://www.vue2editor.com/guide.html#usage) (Modular Version), I should be able to do something like this.

```html
<template>
  <VueEditor
    v-bind="$attrs"
    v-on="$listeners"
  />
</template>

<script>
import { VueEditor } from 'vue2-editor/dist/vue2-editor.core.js'

export default {
  components: {
    VueEditor
  }
}
</script>

<style>
@import '~vue2-editor/dist/vue2-editor.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css';
@import '~quill/dist/quill.bubble.css';
</style>
```

But this is the output.
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: IMO: `@import '~quill/dist/quill.core.css'` is quite important to import too.

Comment: @kissu edited. Nothing changes.